# Even spacing when placing three tikz pictures side-by-side with single y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subcaption

I am attempting to place three figures side-by-side. The figures can then make use of the same y-axis label to save on space. The problem that I am having is that I have to manually place the space between the figures. e.g. iteratively change the values and measure to ensure they are equally spaced. Secondly, the positioning of the caption (a) is centred below its figure, but it does not match the other two.

I have tried many different combinations of \hspace and \hfill, but cant seem to make anything work just right. Then an additional issue (for which I have not supplied code to keep the post short) when adding a tikz legend, the first figure gets a slight vertical shift. This is when using the same code but with the addition of a `\addlegendimage` and `\addlegendentry`

Here is a picture of the issue:
[image: Image_showing_the_issue]

Here is a MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \subcaptionbox{\centering}[0.33\textwidth]{\input{picture_with_label.tikz}}%
        \subcaptionbox{\centering}[0.33\textwidth]{\input{picture.tikz}}%
        \subcaptionbox{\centering}[0.33\textwidth]{\input{picture.tikz}}
\caption{A long caption describing all the figures.}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

The tikz pictures are:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
height=\linewidth,
width=\linewidth,
ymajorticks = false,
]
\addplot [draw=black, fill=black, mark=*, only marks,mark size=1pt]
table{%
x  y
0.459039921422644 0.491633026121641
0.485966183237016 0.502572005351635
};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The only difference for the picture with the label is that the following line is swopped. `ylabel={y}` in place of `ymajorticks = false`.

Comment: Welcome. // One of your problems is that figs b+c have the same (outer) width, while fig a hasn't: it's wider.

Comment: Just to make sure: You do want the white column (space) between adjacent plots be the same, don't you?

Comment: @MS-SPO, Yes exactly.

Comment: Hm, you mixed up a lot of things. Will take a while to get it done. // The easist way, which you may try, is to compile each plot as a .pdf file (add, what's needed to its code), AND use \includegraphics on those pdfs, using [.3\texwidth] etc.

Comment: This is not ideal for the rest of my workflow. I have many of these figures and would really like to get them to work.

Comment: Ok, we are about to abuse comments for discussion. So I suggest you EDIT your question and put some extra-information there about your intended workflow and the work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for groupplots (section 5.8 from pgfplots manual).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{subcaption}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={columns=3, horizontal sep=\columnsep},
  width=0.26\textwidth,
  scale only axis,
  xlabel={\parbox[t]{0.26\textwidth}{\subcaption{}}}]% overkill

\nextgroupplot[ylabel={y}]% xlabel={(a)}
\addplot [draw=black, fill=black, mark=*, only marks,mark size=1pt]
table{%
x  y
0.459039921422644 0.491633026121641
0.485966183237016 0.502572005351635
};

\nextgroupplot[ymajorticks=false]% xlabel={(b)}
\addplot [draw=black, fill=black, mark=*, only marks,mark size=1pt]
table{%
x  y
0.459039921422644 0.491633026121641
0.485966183237016 0.502572005351635
};
\nextgroupplot[ymajorticks=false]% xlabel={(c)}
\addplot [draw=black, fill=black, mark=*, only marks,mark size=1pt]
table{%
x  y
0.459039921422644 0.491633026121641
0.485966183237016 0.502572005351635
};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A long caption describing all the figures.}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, though I wouldn't go your route.

1st, reduce the width inside your plots, which I obtained by trial&error (i.e. from iteration) :

```
% picture.tikz.tex

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=.4\linewidth,
width=.4\linewidth,% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
ymajorticks = false,
]
\addplot [draw=black, fill=black, mark=*, only marks,mark size=1pt]
table{%
x  y
0.459039921422644 0.491633026121641
0.485966183237016 0.502572005351635
};

\end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and

```
% picture_with_label-tikz.tex

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=.4\linewidth,
width=.4\linewidth,% <<<<<<<<<<<
ylabel={y}
]
\addplot [draw=black, fill=black, mark=*, only marks,mark size=1pt]
table{%
x  y
0.459039921422644 0.491633026121641
0.485966183237016 0.502572005351635
};

\end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

2nd, use `subfigure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[a.plot]{\input{picture_with_label.tikz}} 
    \subfigure[b-plot]{\input{picture.tikz}}    
    \subfigure[c-plot]{\input{picture.tikz}}    
    
\caption{A long caption describing all the figures.}
\end{figure} 

%\tikz{
%   \matrix{
%       \input{picture_with_label.tikz} &
%       \input{picture.tikz} &
%       \input{picture.tikz}\\  
%   };
%}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

The commented part below shows a tikz-way. E.g. you can set column sep there as an option. To make that work, DELETE `\begin` and `\end{tikzpicture}` in your plotfiles. Of course, you and and need to put `\nodes {};` to mimick subcaptions, and care for the figure counter yourself ;-)

`\matrix` is to tikz what `\tabular` is to Latex, hence it uses the same syntax. E.g. the subcap-line could read inside this matrix-environment:

```
\node {a-plot}; & \node {b-plot}; & \node {c-plot}; \\
```

Watch the `;` , as each cell is a valid tikz-statement.

Comment: This is great. It's exactly the look I was going for. I'll just have to spend the time iterating the sizes in my document.

Comment: Fine. You can also use absolutely widths like 5cm, if that‘s easier to control.